# Typescript Clean Architecture: How to tackle use case that needs multiple repositories?

Tags: clean-code, clean-architecture

I am implementing clean architecture in my new back-end project and getting stuck with a particular use case.

I have a `CreatePhysicianUseCase` what is responsible for creating a new physician user in my system. I inject my repository into it which has the following methods:

```
export interface CreatePhysicianRepository {
    userExistsById(userId: string): Promise<boolean>

    physicianExistsByUserId(userId: string): Promise<boolean>

    createUser(): Promise<any>

    countryExistsById(): Promise<boolean>

    departmentExistsById(): Promise<boolean>

    hospitalExistsById(): Promise<boolean>

    professionExistsById(): Promise<boolean>

    createPhysician(physician: Physician): Promise<Physician>
}
```

This is the input I am expecting from clients:

```
export interface CreatePhysicianRequestDto {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    professionId: string
    departmentId: string
    hospitalId: string
    countryId: string
}
```

Somewhere I need to verify that the provided `departmentId`, `professionId`, `hospitalId` and `countryId` exists in my database. But I feel like this is not the responsibility of the `CreatePhysicianUseCase`. What would be the proper solution?

**Option 1**

In my `CreatePhysicianController` do I inject multiple `useCases` which will verify that the required, for example, profession exists and remove the `hospitalExistsById()` from the `CreatePhysicianRepository` interface?

**Option 2**

Do I keep the methods in the `CreatePhysicianRepository` and inject respective `DataSources` to the repository in my main module? I know I need to check some of the methods (like `hospitalExistsById)` in other `useCases` as well so if I add these into multiple repositories wouldn't that be a violation of DRY?

**Option 3**

Do I create a common repository for example for `Country` which will have `countryExistsById` method in and I will inject this into the `CreatePhysicianUseCase`?

Maybe there is a fourth option I haven't come up with?

Comment: `Tell, don't ask`. `Tell` the repository to save the new input and let the repository (black box) deal with the ER integrity.